# Find the x-coordinate of the center of mass of a half cylinder.

Tags: calculus

[image]

I know the formula for the x-coordinate is the $$\frac{\int_a^b x\delta A(x) \;\mathrm{dx}}{\int_a^b \delta A(x)\;\mathrm{dx}}$$

So I think I should take 
$$\frac{\int_0^r x\delta \pi r^2 \;\mathrm{dx}}{\int_0^r \delta \pi r^2\;\mathrm{dx}}$$

Since $\delta$, $\pi$, and r are all constants I brought them out front of the integrand and they cancelled so I'm left with 
$$\frac{\int_0^r x \;\mathrm{dx}}{\int_0^r\;\mathrm{dx}}$$ 
\which gives me $\frac{1}{2}$r in the end. Am I doing this problem correctly or not, because logically, an answer of $\frac{1}{2}$r doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Work on your formatting.

Comment: Your formula for $A(x)$ is wrong. The area in question is the area of the intersection of your cylinder with the plane perpendicular to the $x$-axis and passing through the point $(x,0,0)$.

Comment: @Lubin so to find the area of the semicircle in the x-y plane, would I need to do an integral? I guess I'm still confused about that part.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

The x-coordinate of the centroid of the half-disk will give the x-coordinate of the center of mass of the half-cylinder, since the density is constant and the solid has uniform horizontal cross-sections:

Then $\displaystyle\overline{x}=\frac{M_y}{m}=\frac{\int_0^{r}\delta\cdot xl(x)\;dx}{\int_0^{r}\delta\cdot l(x)\;dx}=\frac{\int_0^{r}x\cdot2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\;dx}{\int_0^r 2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\;dx}=\frac{\int_0^{r}x\cdot2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\;dx}{\frac{1}{2}\pi r^2}$

Comment: Why is it that the area is not just $\pi r^2$

Comment: It's because the base is half of a disc.

Comment: This is the argument I would have used.